# Intersection of convex cones

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry

I have the following question:

Let $C$ and $C_i$, $i=1,\dots,m$ convex cones in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that verify:

$\cap_{i=1}^m C_i \neq \emptyset$ and $C\cap C_i \neq \emptyset, \forall i=1,\dots,m$.

Is it true that $\cap_{i=1}^m C_i\cap C \neq \emptyset$?

I know that it's maybe a simple question, but i'm really blocked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Presumably you define a cone as satisfying $tK \subset K$ for $t >0$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume only $x$ is common in all $C_i$. So, $C_i\cap C_j=x$. Also, assume $C\cap C_i =y_i \neq x$. In this case, $\cap_{i=1}^m C_i\cap C = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intuition is a little more obvious in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Consider $C_1 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3| x_1 = 0, x_3 >0 \}$,
$C_2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3| x_2 = 0, x_3 >0 \}$ and
$C=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3| x_1 + x_2=x_3, x_3 >0 \}$.

Note that $(0,0,1) \in C_1 \cap C_2$, $(0,1,1) \in C_1 \cap C$, $(1,0,1) \in C_2 \cap C$ but $C_1\cap C_2 \cap C = \emptyset$.

Now map the above to $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ using the injective linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ by
$Lx = x_1 E_{11}+ x_2 E_{12}+ x_3 E_{21}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you take $C_i=\{x_i=0, \sum x_k> 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ , then the intersection of any $n-1$ of them is non-empty, but the intersection of all $n$ of them is empty. Now you can consider $n=3$

Note: It boils down to the fact that you the [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem) in dimension $d$ ($d=n-1$ here, we look at the cuts with a plane say $\sum x_k =1$ ) requires $d+1$ intersections.